# I cannot 'join' 2 ndarrays of shape (rows,) into one ndarray of shape (rows,2)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
np.MethodSeeBelow((raw_Scaled_CvOPct, raw_Scaled_CvMxPct))
```

- I have tried `np.hstack` and get shape `(rows * 2,)`
- I have tried `np.concatenate` and get shape `(rows * 2,)`
- I have tried `np.stack` and get shape `(2, rows)`
- I have tried `np.vstack` and get shape `(2, rows)`
- I have tried `np.dstack` and get shape `(1, rows, 2)`

Comment: Show what you actually tried. This is important because at least two of these methods will yield correct results if used properly. Does the first line imply that you passed no additional arguments besides the tuple in all cases?

Comment: @Mad Physicist
I do show what I have tried. Simply substitute 'MethodSeeBelow' with the methods **below**. None of the methods work because I did not use axis = 1 as is explained in the correct answer. The shapes of the 2 arrays is explained in the Question Heading. Unfortunately you did not read the whole post. Kindly remove the down vote. Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense. I misread your post. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use stack along axis 1

```
n1 = np.random.random(10)
n2 = np.random.random(10)
n1.shape
> (10,)
s1 = np.stack((n1,n2), axis=1)
s1, s1.shape
> (array([[0.90308381, 0.76712636],
    [0.6700485 , 0.42458683],
    [0.53987017, 0.8661545 ],
    [0.31058594, 0.03774051],
    [0.06994416, 0.74861835],
    [0.70420554, 0.77298267],
    [0.4639175 , 0.37825594],
    [0.07486972, 0.11639835],
    [0.64662856, 0.20703329],
    [0.16519598, 0.55955276]]), (10, 2))
```

Comment: I'm the OP but I cannot vote. However I can thank you Oleg.

Comment: You can select answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the methods you tried can be used to get the desired result, with some slight tweaks:

- `np.hstack(((raw_Scaled_CvOPct[:, None], raw_Scaled_CvMxPct[:, None]))`
- `np.concatenate(((raw_Scaled_CvOPct[:, None], raw_Scaled_CvMxPct[:, None]), axis=1)`
- `np.stack(((raw_Scaled_CvOPct, raw_Scaled_CvMxPct), axis=1)`
- `np.vstack(((raw_Scaled_CvOPct, raw_Scaled_CvMxPct)).T`
- `np.dstack(((raw_Scaled_CvOPct, raw_Scaled_CvMxPct))[0]`
- `np.dstack(((raw_Scaled_CvOPct, raw_Scaled_CvMxPct)).reshape(-1, 2)`

The `stack` method suggested by [@Oleg Butuzov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59556185/2988730) is, in my opinion, the most numpythonic.